# NoSuchMethodError: Class 'List<dynamic>' has no Instance method 'json'

Tags: string, list, flutter, dart, dynamic

first of all, here I want to create an icon button for bookmarking a story. The mechanism is something like when the user clicks on a bookmark icon on a story card, then the field typed list on my Firebase Firestore will record the user id because the user already clicked the bookmark icon. And if the user clicks for the second time, the user id will be removed from the field typed list on the Firestore. But I got an error.

Here is how I create the bookmark icon

```
IconButton(
                      icon: favIcon,
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(
                          () async {
                            if (widget.story.favorite.contains(user.uid)) {
                              widget.story.favorite.remove(user.uid);
                            } else {
                              widget.story.favorite.add(user.uid);
                              await StoryService().updatestory(widget.story);
                              // await _storyReference
                              //     .doc(widget.story.id)
                              //     .update(widget.story.toMap());
                            }
                          },
                        );
                      },
                    ),
```

I also would like to show the method that I use,

```
Future updatestory(StoryModel story) async {
    try {
      await _storyReference.doc(story.id).update(story.toMap());
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

Ok, now the story model part

```
class StoryModel extends Equatable {

  List<String> favorite;
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String author;
  final String imageUrl;
  final double rating;
  final String storytext;

  StoryModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.favorite,
    this.name = '',
    this.author = '',
    this.imageUrl = '',
    this.rating = 0.0,
    this.storytext = '',
  });

factory StoryModel.fromJson(String id, Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      StoryModel(
        id: id,
        name: json['name'],
        author: json['author'],
        imageUrl: json['imageUrl'],
        rating: json['rating'].toDouble(),
        storytext: json['storytext'],
        favorite: json["favorite"] == null
            ? []
            : json["favorite"].json<String>((i) => i as String).toList(),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      id: id,
      "name": name,
      "author": author,
      "imageUrl": imageUrl,
      "rating": rating,
      "storytext": storytext,
      "favorite": favorite,
    };
  }
```

here the screenshot of the field list
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2vXw.png)

But I got an error like this, and I cannot access my screen application anymore.

```
NoSuchMethodError: Class 'List<dynamic>' has no Instance method 'json' 
Receiver: Instance (length: 1) of '_GrowableList' Tried calling: json<String>(Closure: (dynamic) => String)
```

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: `.json<String>((i) => i as String).toList()` what is this supposed to do?

Comment: Check with this code.
`favorite: json["favorite"] == null ? [] : List<String>.from(json["favorite"].map((x) => x)),`

Comment: @nvoigt i thought that is to push the string value into the database because i declared the List<String> favorite;  as one of the properties that a story has

Comment: @DholaHardik Thank you Sir, your answer bring me back to my app screen, and when i clicked on the bookmark icon, the user id is on the list on the database. Once again thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.